# Better way to check variable to avoid multiple conditions for multiple variables

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have below example code where it has three variable defined `job_Name` `out_File` `err_File`.

Now I'm looking to remove this from print statement if any of the variable or all the variables either empty ot not defined

```
job_Name = "Test"
out_File = "/tmp/123"
err_File = "/tmp/321"

print("Job Name {0},Output {1}, Error {2}".format(job_Name,out_File,err_File))
```

ie: `if job_Name is empty` it should print :

```
Output  Error
/tmp/123 /tmp/321
```

Let suppose `out_File` and `err_File` not defined it should only print `job_Name`.

```
Job Name 
Test
```

This can be done with chain conditions  `if` `else` etc.. but looking if that can be avoid as we have multiple such variables and achieved with some smarter or other elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a solution for you, but it'll depend on where those variables come from:

```
error_data = {
    "Job Name": "Test",
    "Output": "/tmp/123",
    "Error": "/tmp/321"
}
line = []
for description, value in error_data.items():
    if(value):
        line.append("{description} {value}".format(description=description, value=value))

print(",".join(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

A little extended but does the trick:

```
job_Name = "Test"
out_File = "/tmp/123"
err_File = "/tmp/321"

headers = ''
output = ''
if job_Name:
    headers += 'Job Name\t'
if out_File:
    headers += 'Output\t'
if err_File:
    headers += 'Error\t'

for val in [job_Name, out_File, err_File]:
    if val:
        output += val + '\t'

print(headers)
print(output)
```

and another approach if your variables have the desired name to print could be this:

```
def retrieve_name(var):
    # prints the given variable's name
    import inspect
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()
    return [var_name for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars if var_val is var]


job_Name = "Test"
out_File = "/tmp/123"
err_File = "/tmp/321"

headers = ''
output = ''

for val in [job_Name, out_File, err_File]:
    if val:
        headers += str(retrieve_name(val)[0]) + '\t'
        output += val + '\t'

print(headers)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do

```
print(f"{'Job Name' + job_Name + ', ' if job_Name else ''}{'Output' + out_File + ', ' if out_File else ''}{'Error' + err_File + ', ' if err_File else ''}")
```

Comment: ...but it's neither nice nor a perfect solution with regards to the commas